# Spring Data JPA and Spring Web Updating Entities Avoiding Associations

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-web

I have the following entities:

- Area
- Listing

They are both many-to-many:

- An area can have many listings
- A listing can have many areas

Both `Area` and `Listing` have other fields like `name`, `domain`, etc.

I'm using Spring Web `RestController` as a way to update the entities.

For example:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public Area update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Area update) {
    return areaRepository.save(update);
}
```

However, as an `Area` can have many thousands of `Listing`s, it's not practical to pass them all in the update request when I just want to update the `Area` name and other basic fields in my web application.

For example, the `update` json in the http request would be:

```
{
  "id" : 69,
  "name" : "San Francisco",
  "domain" : "foo",
  ...
}
```

When serialised, the `area` instance above will have a `listings` field equal to `null` (obviously) and then when saved, all association are remove from this `Area`.

I'm thinking that *I could* do a select-then-update set of operations and only update the values necessary but that is cumbersome - especially when there are many dozens of non-association fields.

The question would be: how can I try to keep to the above code and http request and not remove all of the existing `Listing` associations when saving the input area? Is this possible? I want to update the name and other basic fields but not the association fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BeanUtilBean(org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean).

Step 1: Create custom beanutilbean class.

```
@Component
public class CustomBeanUtilsBean extends BeanUtilsBean {
    @Override
    public void copyProperty(Object dest, String name, Object value)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        if(value==null)return;
        super.copyProperty(dest, name, value);
    }
}
```

Step 2: In your controller while updating. first get the Area from database & use copyProperties method as shown in below.

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public Area update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Area update) {
    Area areaDB = areaRepository.findOne(update.getId());
    customBeanUtilsBean.copyProperties(areaDB,update);//it will set not null field values of update to areaDB.
    return areaRepository.save(areaDB);
}
```

Hope this will helps you..:)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `spring-data-jpa repository` you can write a new method that takes the `changed values of Area` object with `@Modifying` and `@Query` annotations on it.

In the `@Query` you specify the `HQL query with update statement` as in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries)